# Three20 setting thumbnail photo size

Tags: three20, ttphotoviewcontroller

Three20's photo aplication sets the photo size of the photos which are expanded from thumbnail photos. I want to resize the bigger image into thumbnail size keeping the aspect ratio same. But there seems to be no delegate method to do the same. How to set the size of the thumbnail photos?

I'm getting this exception

TTDASSERT failed: 0 == _queue.maxContentLength || contentLength <=_queue.maxContentLength

for one of my photos that's not getting displayed neither on thumbnail nor on expanded view.
How to fix this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out...

Set

[[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

in your application delegate... Setting it to 0 will let any image through, no matter how large..

Comment: If images are too large in size then? What about memory warnings?